# Рандомный показ элемента при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Нужно чтобы при загрузке страницы, показывало один из div

Пример кода:

```
<div class="banner">
<a><img src="#"></a>
</div>

<div class="banner">
<a><img src="#"></a>
</div>

<div class="banner">
<a><img src="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: реализация странная. почему бы не держать один div class="banner" на странице, а средствами php отдавать в него рандомный контент? а будет там 100 баннеров, вы будете все картинки к ним тащить на страницу при каждой загрузке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение в лоб:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="banner">
    <a><img src="#"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="banner">
    <a><img src="#"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="banner">
    <a><img src="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
let container = document.getElementById("container");
let children = container.children;

let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * children.length);

for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if(index != i) {
        children[i].style.display= "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: `let children = document.querySelectorAll("#container .banner");` - есть еще такая штука)

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
   const bannerIndex = randomNum - 1;

   const banner = document.getElementsByClassName('banner')[bannerIndex];
   $(banner).addClass('display');
})
```

CSS:

```
.banner {
    display: none;
}

.banner.display {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Напрашивается вопрос, зачем тут `randomNum`, если он создается с +1, только чтобы потом из него вычесть -1... `const bannerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)`, нет?) А getElementsByClassName (так понимаю, использован только чтобы взять оттуда один элемент), для этого в jQuery есть метод `.eq()` → `$(".banner").eq( bannerIndex ).addClass("display")`